# Change global variable value with a local variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to change a global variable by setting it as a parameter in a function. The problem I'm running into is that my global variable does not change when I change the local variable. I understand that the scope of the variables is what's causing this, but I do not know how to make it work. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    var blnUpgradeGlobal;

    function SelectUpgrade(strUpgradeName, blnUpgradeLocal) {
        if (blnUpgradeLocal) {
            blnUpgradeLocal= false;
            $("#" + strUpgradeName).css("background-color", "#EAC300")
        }
        else {
            blnUpgradeLocal= true;
            $("#" + strUpgradeName).css("background-color", "Lime")
        }
    }

<div id="Upgrade1" onclick="SelectUpgrade(this.id, blnUpgradeGlobal)">
Content
</div>
```

So What I'm trying to accomplish here is so that when the user clicks the div, it toggles the boolean global variable set in the onClick event. I don't want to specify the exact variable in the function because I would then need to write a big nested if statement because there are a bunch of upgrades.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once you set it as function parameter - it will be treated as local variable and the global one won't change!

Comment: Is `blnUpgradeGlobal` used anywhere else, i.e. has it been initialized with a value?

Comment: @Nolo, well any defined variable in JavaScript is initialized with `undefined`, which is falsy.

Comment: @Kay I understand that much :)  My question is on the order of the hard problem of frame of reference...  I've been there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I prematurely submitted my question. What I'm really trying to do here is temporarily link the global variable a local variable so that I do not need to specify the global variable in the function. There are several other upgrades so it would become messy if I had to use a nested if or switch statement.

Comment: @Randell If you are `onclick="SelectUpgrade(this.id, blah)"` on the element of interest, why not supply true or false?  Or is there some other circumstance that determines the global value, such as a timer event etc?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible options:

1. Change the 2nd parameter name (from `blnUpgradeLocal` to something else) in the function declaration
2. Change the global variable value using `window.blnUpgradeGlobal` reference

The former is better

Comment: 3. don't pass that variable as argument ;)

Comment: But the latter shows, that you intentionally changed its value and you know what you are doing (if one is knowing, what he is doing in using global variables)

Comment: @alfasin: the 3rd and the worst :-)

Comment: @Lilith2k3: it depends. If my colleagues saw my code that modifies a global variable (they wouldn't in real life since I don't use ones) - they would know I've done it intentionally

Comment: @zerkms actually, looking at his code, it's the best option :D

Answer (score 3):

a global var can be accessed and changed anywhere in the code.
Get rid of the parameter and then use it.
What is happening is that you are passing in the value of the global but only changing the value of the local var because the local namespace is searched first

Comment: That is certainly **not** the whole point of global variables.  The point of them is to have a value that is the same throughout your application... not some shortcut to having parameters on functions.

Comment: @Brad That's not how I meant my statement to be interpreted, how would you suggest I change it

Comment: I would get rid of your entire first line.  Explaining what is happening is good, but there are often many cases where globals shouldn't necessarily be accessed from within functions.  For something trivial like this, it probably doesn't matter either way.

Comment: @Brad I just want to make sure I am explaining and not just correcting peoples bad code

Comment: @alfasin I can understand his problem with my original wording, even if most people would understand what I meant

Comment: @aaronman I removed my comment since I don't want to "start a fight". I gave +1 to your answer and so did other two people, so it's probably not that bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to specify the exact variable in the function because I would then need to write a big nested if statement because there are a bunch of upgrades

Then your best bet is to have all those global variables wrapped in an object (it's also less pollution in the global namespace). Something like this:

```
var globalVars = {
    foo: true,
    bar: 1,
    baz: 'foo'
};
```

Then, in your function, just reference the object (you may pass it instead, if it's not global):

```
function doStuff(glb) {
    glb.foo = false;
    glb.bar = 2;
}
doStuff(globalVars);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The issue that I'm facing with that is that I don't know what global variable I'm going to be changing when the user clicks. I'm only going to be changing one of those global variables at a time.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misundestood. Now, considering zerkms's answer, what about passing the variable name as a string, and accessing it via `window[varname]`?